# HTML5: what events can I use on a radio input type?

Tags: html, events, input, toggle, onchange

Consider the this example:

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" onchange="init()" value="1" >option1
<input type="radio" name="radio" onchange="init()" value="2">option2
```

JS:

```
function init(){
    alert("Arrrr");
}
```

[As you can see](http://jsfiddle.net/4ca8a/1/), the onchange event doesn't work on a radio input. Which events can I use on a radiobutton? 
I need some kind of input to change between two states that can actually react on a change.

Comment: Google: "which events can I use on a radio button".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your console, the function was actually not defined before the element.

I modified your fiddle to put the function in the `<head>`, it works then: http://jsfiddle.net/4ca8a/4/

Comment: True, but weird. Solves, the posed question, but not my actual problem. With the other forms, the events fire, no matter where in the dcoument the js code is included. And some of the other code, on which that one relies, can't be defined in the head, because some HTML elements are undefined at that stage. Can anyone help me out or provide some readings on that?

Comment: Are you sure your issue is the function is not called? Can you check your console for errors?

Comment: I found a solutions that works, yet is unproper. I still don't understand when to load what code correctly. Any "getElementById" or the-like function can not be called within the head right? Or do i only need to wait till body is loaded? Eg. is it a good idea to start the whole script using the body onload event? Thanks for your help!